# Are Javascript Arrays really Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner to Javascript and learning the concepts. I came across the below code snippet as part of my learning process.

```
<script>
    var data=[];
    data.push("100");
    data.push(100);
    var object=[];
    object.string="100";
    object.number=100;
    data.push(object);
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

The above code snippet defines an Array and pushes a String, Number and an Object into it. I think this violates the definition of an Array which reads as follows:

> Array is a container which can hold a fix number of items and these
>   items should be of the **same type**.

I would like to know if **Array** is the right term to be used in this case as the elements are not of the same type.

Comment: "Should be" is not the same as *must be*.

Comment: Where did you take this definition of *"Array"* from? (E.g.: exact source of the quote)

Comment: He took the definition from Tutorials point's [Data Structures and Algorithms - Arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm) as it seems.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the internet.

Comment: @UnholySheep - Here's the link from where I took the definition of Array - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm

Comment: That's usually the case in other programming languages but not in javascript

Comment: That particular page is *awful* - Not only is it using old/invalid C, some of the code there is straight up wrong (e.g.: The example code for "insertion" has *undefined behavior*). And as others already mentioned, that definition of "Array" is not strictly correct either - it works that way in some programming languages, but not all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand/read them incorrect (in case of javascript).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations. **Neither the length of a JavaScript array nor the types of its elements are fixed.**

And yes, this definition is purely for Javascript. For ex: Java arrays are strictly type based.

Comment: "Java arrays are strictly type based", though technically true, an array could be of type Object, and thus contain Strings and Integers.

Answer (score 0):

The "should be" here most likely refers to the fact that *logically* homogeneous collections are easier to deal with than heterogeneous collections. If you have an array of numbers, you can do aggregate operations such as summing them easily; if you have a mixed array of stuff, you need to pick it apart one by one and can't easily do anything with it. That's often a sign of a badly structured program.

There's no technical reason why collections must be homogeneous, especially in a dynamically typed language like Javascript (more so in statically typed languages).